# Upload an Image with .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I have a form that displays the current data of a member, including his picture.
Below his photo, he can choose to upload another and I replace the old photo in with the new photo in my controller.

My problem is that I can not recover the image in my model, it is always null (the rest goes perfectly).

In my model, I declared a `Member_UploadPicture` variable of type `IFormFile`.

I followed the recent Microsoft tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but nothing works, still null .

I tried with an `@Html.Editor` with the name of the variable and also with an `<input type = file>` but the 2 are always null.

Do you have an idea?

**Model**

```
public class MemberViewModel
{
    public string Member_NameFirst { get; set; }
    public string Member_NameLast { get; set; }

    public byte[] Member_Picture { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Member_UploadPicture { get; set; }
    public string Member_Picture_Show { get; set; }

    // other properties...
}
```

**Controller**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Member, Admin")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMember(MemberViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var MembertoUpdate = new MemberViewModel
        {
          //code
        };

        using (var memomyStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await model.Member_UploadPicture.CopyToAsync(memomyStream);
            MembertoUpdate.Member_Picture = memomyStream.ToArray();
        }
        return Ok(model);
    }
    else return BadRequest();
}
```

**View**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formAll", style = "margin-top:3%", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Personnal</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="formMember" class="row col-xs-12">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="form-check-inline col-xs-12" style="margin-top:2%">
                            <img id="ItemPreview" src="data:image/png;base64, @Model.Member_Picture_Show" style="height:200px; width:200px; margin-left:35%; border:solid 1px black">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check-inline col-xs-12" style="margin-top:2%; margin-left:35%">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Member_UploadPicture, "Upload Picture", new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "test" } })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Member_UploadPicture, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control-file", @id = "Member_UploadPicture" } })
                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="Member_UploadPicture" id="Member_UploadPicture">
                            <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Maximum 1024kb</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

**Ajax Call**

```
function Edit() {

    $(function () {
        $("#formAll").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var formData = $("#formAll").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://localhost:44338/Members/GetMember/",
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    //code
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    //code
                }
            });
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i just noticed that the picture is not in my ajax call, i suppose this is why it comes null in my model.. i've just edited my code with the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `var formData = $("#formAll").serialize();`, it is not able to serialize `IFormFile`, you need to append `IFormFile` to `formData`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#formAll").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('Member_NameFirst', $('#Member_NameFirst').val());
            formData.append('Member_UploadPicture', $('#Member_UploadPicture')[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
                url: "https://localhost:44307/home/getmember",
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    //code
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    //code
                }
            });
        })        })
</script>
```

Comment: Thx for your help. Member_UploadPicture is still null when the controller receive the model (only Member_NameFirst has a value), any guess?

Comment: @Korpin Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: https://github.com/korpinz/jakform --> Here is the .sln, i cant put all the folder since  i've more than 100 files in it.. Could you tell me if you need something more?

Comment: Btw, the View is in Members (from Views file) file :-)

Comment: @Korpin You need to check your code carefully, you have never set `Member_UploadPicture` in [ajax](https://github.com/korpinz/jakform/blob/7548964c17761ae73277a811e02e49ea7c36b65f/Views/Members/Index.cshtml#L319).

Comment: Wow you are right... Im pretty sure i did it because i've copy/paste your code initially but yeah dunno whats happened! It works now.. Sorry for that and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Member_UploadPicture, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control-file", @id = "Member_UploadPicture" } })
```

add to you ajax request

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```